# How to Customize wrapped Antd Button with Styled-Components?

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

I'm having a lot of difficult to target a component wrapping an antd button. All I want to do is to modify the `<button>` tag to have `width: 100%`, but I need to do it from outside of the component. Here is what I have:

##### LogoutButton.js

```js
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { clearSessionCookie } from 'sessions';
import { Button } from 'antd';


function LogoutButton () {
  const { logout } = useAuth0();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    clearSessionCookie();
    return logout({ returnTo: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI });
  }

  return (
    <Button danger type="primary" onClick={handleLogout}>
      Log Out
    </Button>
  );
};

export default LogoutButton;
```

##### HomePage.js

```js
import { LogoutButton } from 'components';
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import { UserOutlined, VideoCameraOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ButtonContainer = styled.li`
    padding: 0 16px;
`;

const StyledLogoutButton = styled(LogoutButton)`
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
`;

function HomePage() {

    return (
        <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
            <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
                nav 1
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<VideoCameraOutlined />}>
                nav 2
            </Menu.Item>
            <ButtonContainer>
                <StyledLogoutButton />
            </ButtonContainer>
        </Menu>
    );
}

export default HomePage;
```

#### The problem:

To modify StyledLogoutButton in HomePage.js in order to correctly set LogoutButton width to 100%. I've tried `&`, `&&&`, using a custom class... nothing seems to work. I can't target the `<button>` html tag.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LogoutButton width="auto" />


function LogoutButton ({width}) {
  const { logout } = useAuth0();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    clearSessionCookie();
    return logout({ returnTo: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI });
  }

  return (
    <Button width={width} danger type="primary" onClick={handleLogout}>
      Log Out
    </Button>
  );
};

const Button = styled.button`
    width: ${({width}) => width ? width : 'auto'}
`;
```

Comment: Thank you! While I would like to target it from *outside* of the LogoutButton component, this works =)